# Is Shashi Tharoor's "Why I Am a Hindu" a valid source?

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations, answers

Can Shashi Tharoor's new book [Why I Am a Hindu](https://www.amazon.in/Why-am-Hindu-Shashi-Tharoor-ebook/dp/B078RNL968/) be used as a source to answer *[Who is considered Hindu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26901/who-is-considered-hindu)*

Or will the answer be taken down?

EDIT:

[An answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27272/2995) using this book as source is now live.

Comment: I would consider it as a valid source, since "Hindu" is more of an identity, than a religion. Even discounting this Qn, any works from famous philosophers (be it politicians of businessmen), should be considered valid; Because there is no degree for one to become a religious Guru.

Comment: What if the author is a Christian or Muslim @iammilind?

Comment: In that case, most of the users won't agree. Rightly, because if a person identifies oneself with other religions, then it may not be suitable for being a "Hindu". Hence their quotes may not be allowed. What if their quotes are from Quran or Bible? Having said that, personally, I would like to see "Hinduism" on an open philosophy grounds. Anyone who don't identify themselves with particular other religion, should be eligible to be quoted. It's analogical to "Linux". Linux may less popular among domestic users, but it's existent everywhere.

Comment: If the answer is touching political issues and about making sensitive comments, that may get deleted. I heard that Shashi Tharoor made some political arguments in the book. Otherwise, there would be no problem IMO.

Comment: @iammilind If the quotes are from Quran or Bible, they will be deleted. No doubt in that. The answers should be from Hinduism point of view It need not to be of a Hindu author. Does it need to be?

Comment: So Zakir Naik's works/commentary on Hinduism are allowed though the community may not like it? The person's faith is of no relevance? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @sv. I expected this type of comment from one or the other. You yourself commented. Obviously not. Such works should not be allowed. The answer should also be respectful and correct also. Works from people who have a good reputation in the community (Hindu community I mean). I would not take example of Zakir Naik. You are naming a Muslim preacher. I am talking about Max Muller, Ralph Griffith when you are taking example of person's faith. You mistook as something else!

Comment: "The answer should also be respectful and correct also." - respectful, agree. What does "correct" mean? I didn't mistake your intent I'm just continuing the conversation to see where the line is drawn. Muslim preacher cannot be an expert in Hindu scripture? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: I think it can be allowed as source on the site. But yet Sastric definition may be recommended over Political authors.

Answer (score 8):

No.

1. Shastra defines who is an aastika and why one must repose faith in god. Shastric input is the only benchmark.
2. Shashi tharoor's work counts as personal opinion. In the context of the sociopolitical zeitgeist.