# Why was this request to undelete the answer rejected by the mods?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, sources-and-citations, moderators

[This top-upvoted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6HFY.png) (to *[Is the Manusmriti written to favor a particular Varṇa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32483)*) written by user17294 (a.k.a [Partha Banerjee](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/391146/partha-banerjee), commonman, Pratimaputra, etc.) back in 2019 was recently deleted by a moderator with the following reason:

> **Source you quoted seems to have prejudice and bias**. I'm deleting this answer. – The Destroyer♦ yesterday

After discovering the answer has been deleted, I updated the answer with [*M N Dutt's translation of Manu Samhita*](https://archive.org/details/The.Dharma.Shastra-Hindu.Religious.Codes-by.M.N.Datta-Volume.5/page/n11/mode/2up) - actual source of English translation of the verses used by OP. This is what I stated in my edit reason:

> **Replace vedkabhed.wordpress.com with the actual source: M N Dutt's translation of Manu Samhita and preserve OP's argument/conclusion**

Following my edit, I also flagged the mods so the answer can be undeleted since my edit addresses the mod's concern:

> vedkabhed.wordpress.com has been replaced with the actual source: M N Dutt's translation of Manu Samhita. This answer can now be undeleted. – sv. 15 hours ago
>
> **declined** - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Not only does the mod decline the flag, he also [rolls back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZhvx.png) my edit with no explanation whatsoever in comments under the post.

Is the source (vedkabhed.wordpress.com or [vedkabhed.com](https://vedkabhed.com/)) really the problem here or the views expressed/conclusion reached ("It's beyond my understanding how an ordained and illumined soul can prescribe punishments with so much of hatred and cruelty") by the user? The same conclusion can be reached by selectively quoting the same verses/translation from the actual source which is what I did in my edit. So the problem is not with the [vedkabhed.com article](https://vedkabhed.com/index.php/2018/05/01/manu-smriti-and-untouchables/) but the way the verses are presented together. Sure, you can accuse OP of cherry-picking verses, but why delete the answer? Lay people, gurus, acharyas, scholars and other users on this site - everyone cherry-picks their favorite scriptures/verses to defend their views. So why isn't this user allowed to cherry-pick verses to reach a certain conclusion?

To me it appears that the mod is trying to censor certain views. Aren't mods supposed to remain neutral to the actual arguments made in a post? Why is the mod reluctant to allow replacing a controversial source with a scholarly source and preserve OP's arguments/conclusion? Why delete a highly-upvoted answer written in 2019, now?

Does SE Inc allow this sort of censorship?

Comment: I might disagree with the deleted answer, however, deleting it seems a blatant example of censorship, IMO.  And yes, everyone, does cherry-pick to reach conclusions, so deleting it incessantly - just because it shows "bias" and "prejudice" in opposition with the "expected" views by several people here, seems too much overarching. And this is just not limited to that question and answer, the roots extends deep. Unfortunately, no-one can do anything, because I guess, being a MOD does comes with some "privileges" and one must be in their "good-books" to prevent censorship.

Comment: @Vivikta Don't assume anything. First of all, it is from a deleted account. User can't add new source now. Moreover, selection of *those* verses was done by some blog author. Now, can anyone find new *valid source* which exactly quote these verses? In case, if you have such source, please quote it and flag mods to undelete the answer. Additionally, it would also be better if *valid source* can conclude opinion of *deleted user* "Do show that these were in fact written by the castiest brahmins to oppress sudras"

Comment: @Vivikta *"the roots extends deep"* - yes, tradition requires strong roots. that's why it's called Sanatan Dharm.

Answer (score 8):

> @sv. Don't try to salvage this answer. Just because you add MN Dutta
> it doesn't make answer proper. Here problem is not who translated but
> "way answer was framed selecting some verses".. That is opinion of
> blog owner and he has drawn certain conclusion and we can't accept
> opinions of some random blog owners as valid sources. – The Destroyer♦

Explanation is already give under answer. Let me explain in detail.

Now, answer was flagged by users about *nature of source*. One can clearly observe bias of blog owner  [by visiting site](https://vedkabhed.com/index.php/author/solomon246rezarprotonmail-com/). It is for this reason why blogs are not allowed as sources. [This answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/3500) and [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2144/3500) clearly explain what kind of sources are allowed. These kind of answers are just personal opinions of some persons and these blog owners are not Rishis or Acharyas.  You  have added MN Dutta as source, still conclusion drawn in answer by selecting some verses which  is *opinion of some random blog Author*. So, it doesn't  qualify as proper source.

> To me it appears that the mod is trying to censor certain views.
> Aren't mods supposed to remain neutral to the actual arguments made in
> a post? Why is the mod reluctant to allow replacing a controversial
> source with a scholarly source and preserve OP's arguments/conclusion?
> Why delete a highly-upvoted answer written in 2019, now?

No views are censored here. All answers with proper sources are allowed. [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46529/3500) says manu has interpolations. It is retained on site. [This highly upvoted answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8999/3500) says Uttara Khanda is interpolation and it is also retained. Please don't assume anything.